# How do I batch encrypt existing passwords in a MySQL db?

Tags: encryption, passwords, bcrypt

I am updating a web system for a client, and his 'accounts' table has over 20,000 users, each with a password field of straight text, meaning none of the passwords are encrypted. (I know, scary!) Anyway, I need to know how to take ALL of these passwords and easily encrypt them, preferably in batch style, and import them back into the db. I couldn't find much in searches. I did see B-Crypt, but that looks to be used mostly for files. I'm pretty novice at this so ANY suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do this.

```
UPDATE table_Users
SET password = EncryptionFunctionYouChoose(password);
```

EDIT
 where "table_Users" is the table where your password is held and "password" is the column name for the password.
END EDIT

Although a better idea would be to hash each password with an individual salt value rather than encrypting.  (my opinion)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know MySQL does not provide in-built B-CRYPT function. [Refer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html). If you just want to solve this issue by using MySQL queries you can do something like

```
update users set password = SHA2(password, 256);
```

But if you do like to BCrypt, I guess you will have to do it at app level.

There are always interesting discussions on storing password in database. See [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=database%20password)